# How to enable HTTPS for management console when using RabbitMQ with Docker

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am trying to build docker image for RabbitMQ SSL enabled server from scratch. After configuring for SSL, Its working for AMQP/SSL but management console is not working with HTTPS.

I Have also enabled SSL configuration for RabbitMQ in rabbitmq.config file.

After building docker and running RabbitMQ server it only enables AMQP over SSL and not enables HTTPS. Management console is still accessible on HTTP only.

**Following is the list of enabled plugins:**

```
[e*] cowboy                            1.0.4
[e*] cowlib                            1.0.2
[  ] rabbitmq_amqp1_0                  3.6.10
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap        3.6.10
[E*] rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl       3.6.10
[  ] rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange 3.6.10
[  ] rabbitmq_event_exchange           3.6.10
[  ] rabbitmq_federation               3.6.10
[  ] rabbitmq_federation_management    3.6.10
[  ] rabbitmq_jms_topic_exchange       3.6.10
[E*] rabbitmq_management               3.6.10
[e*] rabbitmq_management_agent         3.6.10
[  ] rabbitmq_management_visualiser    3.6.10
[  ] rabbitmq_mqtt                     3.6.10
[  ] rabbitmq_recent_history_exchange  3.6.10
[  ] rabbitmq_sharding                 3.6.10
[  ] rabbitmq_shovel                   3.6.10
[  ] rabbitmq_shovel_management        3.6.10
[  ] rabbitmq_stomp                    3.6.10
[  ] rabbitmq_top                      3.6.10
[  ] rabbitmq_tracing                  3.6.10
[  ] rabbitmq_trust_store              3.6.10
[e*] rabbitmq_web_dispatch             3.6.10
[  ] rabbitmq_web_mqtt                 3.6.10
[  ] rabbitmq_web_mqtt_examples        3.6.10
[  ] rabbitmq_web_stomp                3.6.10
[  ] rabbitmq_web_stomp_examples       3.6.10
[  ] sockjs                            0.3.4
```

**Below is the config file:**

```
     [{ssl_config,
          [{cacertfile,
               "/path/to/ca_certificate.pem"},
           {keyfile,"/path/to/server_key.pem"},
           {certfile,
               "/path/to/server_certificate.pem"},
           {port,15671},
       {ssl,true},
           {ciphers,
               ["ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384","ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384",
                "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384","ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384",
                "ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384","ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384",
                "ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384","ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384",
                "DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"]}]}]},
 {rabbit,
     [{ssl_cert_login_from,common_name},
      {ssl_options,
          [{keyfile,"/path/to/server_key.pem"},
           {honor_ecc_order,true},
           {honor_cipher_order,true},
           {certfile,
               "/path/to/server_certificate.pem"},
           {cacertfile,
               "/path/to/ca_certificate.pem"},
           {fail_if_no_peer_cert,true},
           {verify,verify_peer},
           {versions,['tlsv1.1','tlsv1.2']},
           {ciphers,
               ["ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384","ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384",
                "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384","ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384",
                "ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384","ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384",
                "ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384","ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384",
                "DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384","DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384",
                "DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256","DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256",
                "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256","ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
                "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256","ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256",
                "ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256","ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
                "ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256","ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256",
                "DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256","DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
                "DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256","DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256",
                "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA","ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA",
                "DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA","DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA",
                "ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA","ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA",
                "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA","ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA",
                "DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA","DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA",
                "ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA","ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA"]}]},
      {tcp_listeners,[5672]},
      {ssl_listeners,[5671]},
      {auth_mechanisms,['EXTERNAL']},
      {cluster_formation,
          [{peer_discovery_backend,rabbit_peer_discovery_classic_config},
           {node_type,disc}]}]}].
```

Process is kept simple. I just install every thing with Docker file and run the container.

Please suggest what am I doing wrong.

**Edited**
Below is dockerfile content:

```
FROM scratch
#MAINTAINER The IISPL <prafult@interfaceinfosoft.com>

ARG HOST_NAME

ADD ubuntu-bionic-core-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz /

LABEL name="Ubutnu Base Image"
LABEL vendor="Ubutnu 18.04"
LABEL license=GPLv2

ENV HOST_MACHINE_HOSTNAME=$HOST_NAME

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install adduser wget make git gnupg gnupg2 gnupg1 vim python3 init-system-helpers openssl logrotate socat systemd erlang erlang-nox -y && \
    apt-get autoclean && \
    apt-get autoremove && \
    apt-get -y upgrade

RUN apt-get install -y rabbitmq-server

#ENV RABBITMQ_VERSION 3.6.12

#RUN wget https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v$RABBITMQ_VERSION/rabbitmq-server_$RABBITMQ_VERSION-1_all.deb && \
#    dpkg -i rabbitmq-server_$RABBITMQ_VERSION-1_all.deb && \
#    rm -rf rabbitmq-server_$RABBITMQ_VERSION-1_all.deb && \

RUN mkdir -p /home/rabbitmq_server/scripts
RUN mkdir /home/rabbitmq_server/ssl

COPY scripts /home/rabbitmq_server/scripts
COPY ssl /home/rabbitmq_server/ssl
COPY rabbitmq.config /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
RUN chmod +x /home/rabbitmq_server/scripts/*.sh
RUN chmod -R 777 /home/rabbitmq_server/ssl/

RUN systemctl enable rabbitmq-server.service

RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl

EXPOSE 5671 15672 5672 15671

CMD ["/home/rabbitmq_server/scripts/run.sh"]
```

And in the run script I just run the RabbitMQ server.

Comment: I don't know what `management console` means exactly? Do you mean [rabbitmqadmin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html)? I think `rabbitmqadmin` can work with rabbitmq HTTP API with TLS.

Comment: Thank you for noticing @menya.. By management console I mean the web UI which rabbitmq server provide by default on HTTP when management plugin is active.. I am trying to enable HTTPS in the same. To achieve that I have also provided SSL configuration for rabbitmq management and I have deployed it with inside a docker container. But HTTPS (Port : 15671) is not enabled.
Point is:
When I deploy RabbitMQ with same configuration without docker HTTPS gets enabled but When I deploy RabbitMQ with docker HTTPS doesn't get enabled.

Comment: So which image you use? [Offical image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq)? It can enable SSL by Env directly.

Comment: No I am building RabbitMQ from scratch.With docker file I have build an Ubuntu container and have installed RabbitMQ as we do in Normal standalone machine. But the configuration works for standalone setup but not with docker image setup.

Comment: Can you provide your Dockerfile?

Comment: @menya I just added Dockerfile content. Please check and let me know if something is wrong with it

Comment: I think you probably miss `erlang-ssl` or something else. Is there any special reason not to use the offical image? I think deploying rabbitmq manually is difficult, it need complex steps from [offical guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html) and [TLS guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html).

Comment: I am trying to build from scratch because of user control. In provided image I may not get the full control over the server configuration.